# How can I pass the XSLT file location which is in my package in java to Transformer?

Tags: java, xml, xslt, path, filepath

I have my xslt file in package structure **com/test/application/meta/xslt/forgotPassword.xslt**

```
TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Source xslDoc = new StreamSource("/com/test/application/meta/xslt/forgotPassword.xslt");
    Source source = new StreamSource(new StringReader(getXmlData()));
    try {
        Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(xslDoc);
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        transformer.transform(source, new StreamResult(writer));
        String output = writer.toString();
        return output;
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**Getting error:**

```
FATAL ERROR:  '/com/test/application/meta/xslt/forgotPassword.xslt (No such file or directory)'
```

When I am trying with

```
Source xslDoc = new StreamSource("com/test/application/meta/xslt/forgotPassword.xslt");
```

**I am getting this error:**

```
FATAL ERROR:  '/var/lib/tomcat7/com/test/application/meta/xslt/forgotPassword.xslt (No such file or directory)'
```

How can I pass the correct file location to `Transformer` ? The file is in package **com/test/application/meta/xslt/forgotPassword.xslt**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you move your xml file to src/main/resources ? Or its somehow auto-generated ?

If you can move it to resources folder, that code can help you do the job

```
 InputStream stream = YourClassName.class.getResourceAsStream("/xslt/forgotPassword.xslt");
 Source schemaSource = new StreamSource(stream);
```